# Windows: Execute ping command using QProcess::execute without command prompt

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am trying to determine with C++ and Qt5 if a specific IP-Address is reachable with this command:

```
int c =  QProcess::execute("ping -n 1 www.google.de");
qDebug() << "test" << c;
```

It is working fine but the command prompt shows up for a second. Is there a way to get the ping process work in the background without this window?

Comment: I have tested the code. It does not show any command prompt. Just using `QProcess p; int c =  p.startDetached("ping -n 1 www.google.de");` brings the command prompt window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember rightly, if you change `execute` to `start` it won't show the command window. If that doesn't work you might want to look at using QNetwork to test reachability yourself, it shouldn't be too difficult to do.